# Getting offline token alongside refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, openid-connect, keycloak

I am using Authorisation Code Flow in my web application. I would like to get a refresh token for the web app itself but also an offline token that I will save in the database so I can use it later on for an offline task.

However I am struggling with that. I cannot use grant-type password because I don’t want to ask the user again to enter his/her credentials and also authorisation code is only one-time use so I cannot integrate it with the current flow.

Is there any other way to generate an offline token from a different token? I have tried using grant type refresh-token with scope offline_access but that didn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After keep working with Keycloak for several months, the answer is simple: it is not possible.

Offline token is effectively a refresh token with no expiration time so you can get one or the other but never both as part of the same request/response.

From a user point of view, we created a new page to request this token using password grant-type and offline scope. User need to re-enter his password but it seems ok from a security point of view. This approach works for us given the requirements to get this token as it is an unusual task.

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate offline tokens using service account, check keycloak documentation on [service account](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_admin/topics/clients/oidc/service-accounts.html).

Following [discussion](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2015-November/003523.html) will help you to understand different scenarios generating and using offline tokens

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, service account will give me a token in behalf of the client itself whereas what I need is to get a token in behalf of the user connected to the webapp.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you find a way to get and offline token without login again?